# Compilation error in HelloWorld C program in C-Free Pro-5 called Dwarf Error

Tags: c

I am using the Windows 8 pro. I recently installed C-free professional 5 in it. When I compiled a simple hello world c program I got an error while compiling it called as dwarf error. It said something like this.

```
[Error] Dwarf Error: Offset (700) greater than or equal to (null) size (4954657).
```

The hello world program is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've never heard of C-Free before, but I'd recommend trying out Visual Studio Express.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Mat, Dwarf Errors seem to be a GCC thing according to my google searches

Comment: @ctor [Not really](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF).

Comment: C-free comes with its inbuilt GCC compiler.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, funnily enough (unless someone set an option to cavil about `main()` vs `main(void)`).  So, it would appear that somehow your system is not working correctly.  You mention `dwarf`; did you specify some option to make it work with Dwarf files, or is that its default mode?  Is the C-free system certified to work on Windows 8?  If it's certified to work, then we might wonder whether the install was successful.  Google search on 'c-free 5' suggests it was released in late 2010; it might not work on Windows 8.

Comment: Do you think you can paste the _exact_ error message in here? What you typed there doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's absolutely *nothing* wrong with that code although it would be better with one of the two canonical forms of `main`:

```
int main (void) { ...
```

Therefore your problem lies with the environment. It appears from some investigation that:

- the CFree web site and product haven't been updated any time in the last three+ years;
- it only purports to support up to Windows 7;
- it looks like it's run as one of those typical one or two-man operations, with little active support; and
- it uses a proprietary licence.

Because of all that, I would *strongly* suggest switching to a product that will give you better support.

For example, Code::Blocks appears to have most, if not all, of the features claimed by C-Free. On top of that, it uses a GPL3 license, you can get it and use it for zero cost, and has a very active community behind it for support services, rather than a single email address somewhere in China that may or may not respond/exist :-)

[Dwarf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF), by the way, is a debugging format, so my best guess at the problem would be that the IDE isn't very well matched to the underlying tools, a good reason to avoid it in my opinion.